# How to change css style by using Unicode Hexadecimal

Tags: javascript, html, css, unicode, escaping

Here is my code:

```
<script>window.onload=function(){
document.body.innerHTML="<p style=font-family:\22arial\22>hello</p>";
}
</script>
```

\22 should be “ , however, the result page turns out to totally ignore them:

[image]

But whats interesting is that if i used HTML Entity Name `"&quot;"` :

```
    <script>window.onload=function(){
    document.body.innerHTML="<p style=font-family:&quot;arial&quot;>hello</p>";
    }
    </script>
```

[image: after I used entity name]
the result page is exactly what I want
Is it something related to the encoding / decoding method my browser use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about unicode characters, the notation should be `'\u0022'`. That one works for me when I test it:

```
alert("He said: \u0022Hello, World!\u0022");
```

But for a quote, you could also use a backslash to escape the quote character itself:

```
alert("He said: \"Hello, World!\"");
```

or use a single quoted string:

```
alert('He said: "Hello, World!"');
```